# Find value in position X in string

Tags: php

I have a string `(product sku): TC00111009` (as example, it can be `TTIIIIIII (T=Text,I=Integer)`)

How I can check that 4th position's `TC00[1]11009` value is `1` or `2`? Which php functions will fit for this?

Comment: http://php.net/strpos

Comment: `strpos` documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be interested in PHP's [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) function:

```
$value = substr($string, 3, 1);
if (($value == 1) || ($value == 2)) {
    // it's equal to 1 or 2

} else {
    // something else

}
```

You can also use direct string-index accessing (i.e. treating the string like an array):

```
$value = $string[3];
```

If you take this approach, make sure your string is long enough first: `if (strlen($string) > 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way. Positions start with `0` so `3` is the 4th position:

```
$string = 'TC00111009';

if($string[3] == 1 || $string[3] == 2) {
    //yes
}
```